# directory is not created

Tags: php, directory

I am a beginner in php my code to create a directory is given below.

```
<?php


        if($_POST["create"])
        { 
            $name=$_POST["newDirCreated"];
            $uploaddir = $name;
            mkdir($uploaddir,0777);
            print "created";
        }


?>
```

But directory is not created using this. If i want create a directory in public_html how can i do it?

Comment: `mkdir` does not throw exceptions. The try/catch is redundant.

Comment: basically i am a java programmer thats why i put that try catch. let me chek it again

Comment: is your `$_POST['create']` a Boolean or string or numeric?

Comment: Do you have permission to create in the folder? Also, I'd be careful with the makedir code, it's taking a directory name in from the user which could be pointed anywhere.

Comment: @Mic1780  thanks for your advice problem was with that $_POST["create"]

Comment: codeigniter core has this beautiful function: `is_really_writable` @https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Common.php

you can do `$flag = is_really_writable(".");` to find out if the current directory is writable. If it is, you shouldn't have a problem with `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mkdir()](http://docs.php.net/mkdir) doesn't throw an exception when something goes wrong. You have to make your script a little bit more "talkative" to get more information about what's going on

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

if( !isset($_POST["create"]) ) {
    echo 'post parameter create not present';
}
else {
    // you are absolutely sure about passing the POST parameter as-is to mkdir() ?
    // ok, it's up to you; just make sure it doesn't get abused....
    echo 'current working directory: ', htmlspecialchars(getcwd()), "<br />\n";
    echo 'newDirCreated: ', htmlspecialchars($_POST["newDirCreated"]), "<br />\n";
    $rc = mkdir($_POST["newDirCreated"], 0777);
    if ( $rc ) {
        echo 'created';
    }
    else {
        echo "an error occured<br />\n";
        if ( function_exists('error_get_last') ) {
            echo 'error_get_last: ', htmlspecialchars(print_r(error_get_last(), true));
        }
        else if ( isset($php_errormsg) ) {
            echo 'php_errormsg: ', htmlspecialchars($php_errormsg);
        }
        else {
            echo 'no additional error information available';
        }
    }
}
```

But remember to make it less talkative (yet handling error conditions) again after debugging. You shouldn't expose all the inforamtion to arbitrary users...

see also:

- http://docs.php.net/reserved.variables.phperrormsg
- http://docs.php.net/error_get_last

Comment: OK i will change that, I will give myown name for the directory.